# Insert Into...Select - get and use autoincrement ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table which contains all information about a player. What I'd like to do is take this information and split the data into different tables. For example:

Table PlayerData has all the information. Table `Address` holds information about the player's residence and table `Info` holds information such as Name, date of birth and the Address ID (pointing to the `Address` table).

I can use an `INSERT INTO...SELECT` to copy data across. However, my issue comes in doing this sequentially such that the correct ID outputted from the Address table is inserted into the Info table otherwise there would be a mix up between which address belongs to which player. How can I get the identity created for an Address insert and use that in the subsequent Staff insert?

Speed is not a priority as this is only done once to initialise the database, the integrity is crucial.

Thanks

Comment: BTW `Info` is not really a good name for a table. It does not really describe the content of the table.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the names of the tables for this question. Real table names are different :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using foreign keys to reference a main table. Now I've kept this simple but if you can follow this then you will be able to edit it for your needs.

Ok, let's make some sample data. This is an equivalent of your current table;

```
CREATE TABLE PlayerData (PlayerID int, PlayerName varchar (20), DateOfBirth date, Address1 varchar(20), Address2 varchar(20))
INSERT INTO PlayerData (PlayerID, PlayerName, DateOfBirth, Address1, Address2)
VALUES
(1,'Mike Hunt','1980-01-01','Mike Street','Hunt Town')
,(2,'Harry Dong','1970-02-02','Harry Street','Dong Town')
,(3,'Hugh Gass','1960-03-03','Hugh Street','Gass Town')
,(4,'Neil Down','1950-04-04','Neil Street','Down Town')
,(5,'Seymore Butts','1940-05-05','Seymore Street','Butts Town')
```

I'm going to create one table that holds a unique list of my player id numbers, this is where I would put a little further information that doesn't fit into the other tables. For this example I've just got the one field;

```
CREATE TABLE PlayerNum (PlayerID int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
```

I'm now going to make my new AddressData table. Notice it's got it's own identity field but also has a PlayerID that will reference the PlayerNum table;

```
CREATE TABLE AddressData (AddressID int identity(10,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, PlayerID int, Address1 varchar(20), Address2 varchar(20), FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID) REFERENCES PlayerNum(PlayerID))
```

I'm going to do the same for the table that will contain my player's personal info;

```
CREATE TABLE PlayerPersonalInfo (InfoID int identity(50,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, PlayerID int, PlayerName varchar(20), DateOfBirth date, FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID) REFERENCES PlayerNum(PlayerID))
```

So I've now got my new 3 tables that are empty and one table with data to insert into them.

Let's first populate our PlayerNum table, this needs to be first because of the foreign key constraints on the other tables;

```
INSERT INTO PlayerNum  (PlayerID)
SELECT PlayerID 
FROM PlayerData
```

Now I've done that, let's insert our data into AddressData. Notice I'm not inserting data into the AddressID field as it's an identity field. It will start from 10 and increment by 1 as per the table definition;

```
INSERT INTO AddressData (PlayerID, Address1, Address2)
SELECT PlayerID, Address1, Address2
FROM PlayerData
```

I'm going to do the same with my PlayerPersonalInfo data. The identity for this table will start from 50 and increment by 1;

```
INSERT INTO PlayerPersonalInfo (PlayerID, PlayerName, DateOfBirth)
SELECT PlayerID, PlayerName, DateOfBirth
FROM PlayerData
```

You can now get rid of the PlayerData table if you're confident you don't need it.

```
DROP TABLE PlayerData
```

You'll now have 3 tables;

**PlayerNum**

```
PlayerID
1
2
3
4
5
```

**AddressData**

```
AddressID   PlayerID    Address1        Address2
10          1           Mike Street     Hunt Town
11          2           Harry Street    Dong Town
12          3           Hugh Street     Gass Town
13          4           Neil Street     Down Town
14          5           Seymore Street  Butts Town
```

**PlayerPersonalInfo**

```
InfoID  PlayerID    PlayerName      DateOfBirth
50      1           Mike Hunt       1980-01-01
51      2           Harry Dong      1970-02-02
52      3           Hugh Gass       1960-03-03
53      4           Neil Down       1950-04-04
54      5           Seymore Butts   1940-05-05
```

Notice that the PlayerID in the final two tables can now be linked to PlayerNum in order to retrieve your data.

As we're using foreign keys, you cannot have a player with information in AddressData or PlayerPersonalInfo without a corresponding entry in PlayerNum

Comment: Great answer, thanks! But regarding the extra PlayerID column, is there any difference from simply using the AddressData.AddressID as the PK and FK for the PlayerPersonalInfo table that has the AddressID column in it? Because the address is unique, I've been using the AddressID as the FK (and PK)

Comment: It all depends on what other information you need to store. I'd generally have the player as the unique field, that way you can have multiple addresses for one person (as an example) for if they move home or similar. It would allow you to keep the old data for audit purposes and only join the latest data if you're looking for their current address.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. I have an audit table showing all changes but I understand the advantage you mean since it's all in one place. It would require quite a bit of refactoring on my part (existing stored procs etc...) to implement the version above

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't sure what sort of system you are currently working with and what sort of changes you could make. I'm sure you know what approach will work for you best. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply though, it's something I'd bear in mind for other projects. Having said that, still looking for a solution to this question so may well end up refactoring and using this method if need be

Answer (score 3):

If you are learning how to do this, then learn the right way:  the `OUTPUT` clause (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)).

This allows you to put the results into a temporary table (usually a table variable).  An example is:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (AddressId int);

INSERT INTO ADDRESS( . . .)
    OUTPUT inserted.AddressId INTO @ids
    VALUES ( . . . );

INSERT INTO info( . . ., AddressId)
    SELECT . . . , i.AddressId
    FROM @ids i;
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this but I'm getting `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Info'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Info'. The duplicate key value is (12).` It seems the code is running in loops as the table itself is initially empty